# Se me duplica un select pero cuando traigo un dato de la BD

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario donde entre otras cosas tengo un select multiple donde se seleccionan tipos de trabajos que hace el usuario.
Cuando se da de alta, elige en un select estos items y los graba en la BD con el formato de ["1","2","4"] siendo esos numeros los ids de lo que eligió.
Ahora bien, ahora estoy analizando la posibilidad de que pueda modificar esos datos, entonces lo llevo a una pagina de edición del perfil y el mismo select lo cargo asi:

```
<select id="tipoUsuario" class="ui fluid search dropdown" multiple name="clase[]">
                    <option value="0"></option>
                    <?php
                        //Traigo el array del perfil
                        $valores = json_decode ($clase, true);

                        $conexion = new Conexion();
                        $stmt = $conexion -> prepare("SELECT idclase, clase FROM usuarios_clase WHERE vigente = 1 AND visible = 1 ORDER BY idclase");
                        $stmt->execute();
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            foreach ($valores as $key => $value) {
                                if ($value == $row['idclase']) { ?>
                                    <option value = "<?php echo $row['idclase']?>" selected><?php echo utf8_encode($row['clase'])?></option>
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <option value = "<?php echo $row['idclase']?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($row['clase'])?></option>
                                <?php }
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
```

Lo que me ocurre es que si por ejemplo el usuario no seleccionó nada en el registro, en la BD grabo un ["0"] y el select se carga perfectamente en el proceso de edición. 
Pero si el usuario tiene algo cargado, es decir, eligió algunos items, los items que se cargan en el select se duplican. Quiero decir por ejemplo si eligió "trabajo A", "trabajo B", "trabajo D" en el select me aparecen 
"trabajo C"
"trabajo C"
"trabajo E"
"trabajo E"
"trabajo F"
"trabajo F"

y lo peor de todo es que no entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal...

Si me pueden dar una mano se los agradezco !!!
Saludos

Comment: podes asegurar que el registro en la BD esta una sola vez? y no quiero preguntar, pero esto es una muy mala manera de guardar estos datos.

Comment: no no no usuarios_clase (es clase de trabajo) 1 = pintura, 2 = albañilería, 3 = carpintería (etc) en el usuario guardo que trabajos hace, si el el 1, el 3, y el 5 ponele.

Comment: tienes un error de logica!, recorres N veces los registros que seleccionastes, tienes dos for por ende cuando haces el segundo (que valida) lo agrega

Comment: es un select multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un error de logica estas haciendo un `for` por cada registro de base de datos realizas un `if` y luego lo insertas!, una opcion rapida ,optimizada es usando [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php)

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if (in_array($row['idclase'] , $valores)) { ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $row['idclase']?>" selected><?php echo utf8_encode($row['clase'])?></option>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo $row['idclase']?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($row['clase'])?></option>
        <?php }
}
```

Comment: falto mas lectura me falto un parentesis xD

Comment: Gracias Jack !!!